# Relation between kernel size and input size in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, convolution

I have a Conv1D layer in keras with a kernel size of 3 and a stride length  of 1.
I have the following error when I'm trying to handle input size of 5 but everything works with input size of 6.

```python
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Computed output size would be negative:
-1 [input_size: 0, effective_filter_size: 3, stride: 1]
```

I thought that kernel of size 3 needs input of size at least 3.

EDIT: Here is the model, the input size is variable, the problem I have is with input of size 5.

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(
    input_shape=(None, 4),
    filters=64,
    kernel_size=3,
    activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=3,
    activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(
    filters=16,
    kernel_size=2,
    activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(number_of_classes))
model.add(Softmax(axis=-1))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Yep, look at my edit

Comment: Where did you mention the input size of 5? Also, please specify the full stack trace

Comment: `input_shape=(None, 4)` Same data have input size of 5, or 6, 7, ... I have this problem only with sequence of size 5.

Comment: Try using 'same' padding

Comment: Or specify the sequence length in your input shape as `input_shape=(5,4)`

Comment: Thanks ! I wasn't paying attention that there was a "valid" padding !

Comment: Ok I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the size of your output feature maps is the same as your input feature maps, you have to pad the input using 'same' padding.

```
model.add(Conv1D(
    input_shape=(None, 4),
    filters=64,
    kernel_size=3,
    activation='relu',
    padding='same'))
```